# Which driver (and PPD version) is my printer using?

Tags: drivers, printing

As printing is sometimes unusually slow on my system, I'd like to check which driver my printer is using. I'm not sure if the driver version and the [PPD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript_Printer_Description) version amount to the same thing; if you know the difference, please explain briefly.

Neither `http://localhost:631/` nor the standard printing config GUI seem to offer any insights regarding drivers or PPD version numbers.

Answer (score 6):

There's version info in the PPD file itself (it's only text).

You can see this for yourself with the command `grep Version /etc/cups/ppd/YourPPD.ppd` where YourPPD.ppd is the name of your PPD file.

Here's an example from my system for illustration purposes:

```
~$ grep Version /etc/cups/ppd/DCP7065DN.ppd 
*FormatVersion: "4.3"
*FileVersion: "1.00"
*LanguageVersion: English
*cupsVersion:   1.1
*PSVersion: "(3010.106) 3"
```

According to what I see here, my PPD file is [Format 4.3](https://web.archive.org/web/20160813043851/http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/ps/5645.PPD_Update.pdf) and it shows that I'm using the PostScript 3 driver version 3010.106.

For more about PostScript versions and the differences between them see [this](https://www.thoughtco.com/difference-adobe-postscript-levels-1074580).

For more about the creation of PPD files [look here](https://www.cups.org/doc/postscript-driver.html#CREATING).

Answer (score 2):

In the standard printer config GUI:

- **Printer Options**
- *scroll down*, **PPD Version**

Comment: and furthermore: the PPD already corresponds to the most recent one offered on the manufacturer's site.

Comment: On 17.04 using an HP I can't see this option.

Comment: Normally HP is using hplip - package ?! - you could install package hplip and then after this go to terminal and type : sudo hp-setup - there you can watch your driver being installed.

Comment: Not sure which desktop environment you suggested, but in Gnome, the "standard printer config GUI" does not have "Printer Options"

Answer (score 0):

The following command lists PPD files for printers that have been added to the system.

```
ls /etc/cups/ppd/*.ppd
```

Comment: Cool, but this does not answer the question of which driver is in use.