# where are the printer drivers

Tags: networking, drivers, printing, filesystem, canon

I have a ppd file somewhere on my PC, to a specific printer. Where do I go to find that PPD file?
I looked around in /usr/share/cups but I didnt see any specific to my device files. But maybe, Im not looking for the right thing.

Here is a segment of the printer set up:
`cat /etc/cups/printers.conf`

```
<DefaultPrinter Durp>
UUID urn:uuid:dbf63043-fa91-00-71a4-6dea70508ddc
Info Canon iR-ADV 4245/4251 PPD
Location Room
MakeModel Canon iR-ADV 4245/4251 PPD
DeviceURI socket://address:9100/
State Idle
StateTime 1475107341
ConfigTime 1475107011
Type 8433876
Accepting Yes
Shared Yes
JobSheets none none
QuotaPeriod 0
PageLimit 0
KLimit 0
OpPolicy default
ErrorPolicy retry-job
Attribute marker-colors \#000000,none,#000000
Attribute marker-levels 13,-1,-1
Attribute marker-names Canon GPR-42 Black Toner,Waste Toner,Black Drum Unit
Attribute marker-types toner,waste-toner,opc
Attribute marker-change-time 1475107341
</DefaultPrinter>
```

From this, I cannot see where the Foomatic driver is, or what ppd file it is using. Should I be looking for a specific PPD file for the printer?
In /etc/cups/ppd/ I see a ppd file for the printer in question, but where did it come from, and how was it made? where is the thing that originated the PPD file? The ppd files, in /etc/cups/ppd are just the ones in use. Is there a complete list somewhere else?

Comment: Pick one from `/etc/cups/ppd` and do a `locate {ppd}` If those are stored anywhere else (like `/usr/share/ppd`) the one you need to find is there too.

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/276437/which-driver-and-ppd-version-is-my-printer-using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look under `/usr/share/ppd`, there might be a sub-directory or 2 but ultimately your driver should be somewhere there.

Comment: The ones  was looking for got put somewhere else,  in /usr/share, but the insight got me looking in the right place! Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

The file printers.conf is regularly read and updated by the cups daemon.  The technology used behind the scene is mdns, based on Bonjour or Zeroconf, which allows devices on your local network to publish services. In recent version of Ubuntu this is implemented by the avahi-daemon. The services published can be listed with `avahi-browse -at`. The option -a is for all and the option -t is to tell not to keep listening and terminate. In my case, when I disconnect my printer, it lists nothing. If I reconnect it, it lists a lot of available connections published by the printer. If I turn off the printer, the avahi daemon notices it and it lists nothing again.

Related to this, I had the issue that in Settings -> Printers, many printers were shown which I could not find locally using `lpstat -p`. They were found by the avahi-daemon in the connection associated with the printer. I could not find any configuration of the avahi-daemon to avoid that : any configuration that prevented the discovery of the extra printers would also break the otherwise correct printer. I had to modify the network configuration of the printer itself.  I removed all ways to allow discovery, all features, except the basic ipv4, ipv6, dhcp, Bonjour and IPP. I restarted the avahi-daemon and the cups daemon and I only had the correct printer in  Settings -> Printers.

Of course, this is not a solution if the printers is in a network where the other features might be needed. In this general case, the solution would require a more flexible avahi daemon or a more flexible interface offered by settings->Printers or something with the required flexibility in between these two, say the cups daemon.